# How to change the background color when I click a <li> in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ng-style

I have a kind of side bar menu. Like this:

```
 Projects: 
       All
       project1
       project2
```

When I click an item I want to changed it the background-color. (from black to green).

```
Projects: 
           All
           project1 // This was clicked and I want to be GREEN
           project2
```

But, what I did until now was to changed the color for all of the projects when I clicked a project. All of them are green know. I don't know how to do that for a particular item.

```
<div class="container">
  <h5>Projects: </h5>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav side-nav">
      <li routerLinkActive="active" class="nav-item">
        <a (click)="activeProject()" [ngStyle]="{'background-color':isActiveProject? 'green' : 'white' }" routerLink="/tasks" href="#">All</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav side-nav" *ngFor="let project of projects">
      <li routerLinkActive="active" class="nav-item" >
        <a (click)="activeProject()" [ngStyle]="{'background-color':isActiveProject? 'green' : 'white' }" [routerLink]="['/tasks/project/', project.projectId]" href="#">{{project.projectName}}</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

In the component:

```
isActiveProject: boolean;

activeProject() {
    this.isActiveProject = true;
  }
```

I suppose that this active project method is apply for all the li elements, an remains active when it was stetted on true.

Comment: instead of a boolean value, store the active project as a string, then you can check for individual equality

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see you have a `routerLinkActive="active"`, this should set the `active` class on the `li` element. Then in your CSS, you can do:

```
li.nav-item.active { background: green; }
```

You may have to set `[routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}"` for exact routing and highlighting.

Then you can get rid of `isActiveProject` for the change of background color and the `ngStyle`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to store the index of the active project and compare it to the item in the ngFor loop:

Component:

```
public activeProjectIndex: number;

public activeProject(index: number): void {
  this.activeProjectIndex = index;
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav side-nav" *ngFor="let project of projects; let i = index">
   <li routerLinkActive="active" class="nav-item" >
     <a (click)="activeProject(i)" [ngStyle]="{'background-color': activeProjectIndex === i ? 'green' : 'white' }" [routerLink]="['/tasks/project/', project.projectId]" href="#">{{project.projectName}}</a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can track the clicked item properties ($event.target or whatever you need) by adding the "$event" property in your click function: 
`<a (click)="activeProject($event)"`

You also have access to `routerLinkActive` decorator, so you can also hook your current menu item by its parent class

Answer (score 0):

Please try this, this will initially set green background for 'All' and change the background of the tab when you clicked on it

HTML

```
<div class="container">
<h5>Projects: </h5>
<div class="container-fluid">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav side-nav">
 <li routerLinkActive="active" class="nav-item">
    <a (click)="activeProject = 'all'" [ngStyle]="{'background-color':activeProject == 'all' ? 'green' : 'white' }" routerLink="/tasks" href="#">All</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav side-nav" *ngFor="let project of projects">
  <li routerLinkActive="active" class="nav-item" >
    <a (click)="activeProject = project.projectId" [ngStyle]="{'background-color':activeProject ==  project.projectId? 'green' : 'white' }" [routerLink]="['/tasks/project/', project.projectId]" href="#">{{project.projectName}}</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Component

```
activeProject='all'
```